# JDO in Google App Engine: order of keys in unowned one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm implementing web application with JDO in Google App Engine.

According to [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships), in owned one-to-many relationships, order of elements in "owner" object collection is determined either by automatically created index field, or by information given in explicit ordering clause. For example:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Person {

    // ...

    @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="list-ordering", value="country asc, city asc"))
    private List<ContactInfo> contacts = new List<ContactInfo>();
```

In unowned relationships, "owner" object contains collection of keys of "nested" objects, for example:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Author {

    // ...

    @Persistent
    private List<Key> books;
```

Is order of keys preserved, if I use List<Key> collection in "owner" object for storing keys of "nested" elements?

I could not find answer neither in [JDO relationships](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Unowned_Relationships) article, nor in [Data Classes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Collections) article :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering of `List`s in general is preserved, `List<Key>` included.